How to replace JSON value under a key that starts with a phrase
I have a table named report, which contains a JSON type column called data.
I want to do two things:

Find the key start with "number" and update its value to number 123. For example, record1
{"number_01": 14322, "number_98": 629578}

will be updated to
{"number_01": 123, "number_98": 123}


Find the value contains "http://139.168.6.44", whatever key's name, and replace value with "http://139.168.6.55". For example, record1
{file: "http://139.168.6.44/upload"} 

will be replaced with
{file: "http://139.168.6.55/upload"}



Additionally, I do not know the data structure in advance, and the fields that start with "number" could be located at any nested level.
I tried run the code to update number value, but it does not work, the code run a very long
DO $$
    DECLARE
      _keys_to_update TEXT[];
      _key TEXT;
    BEGIN
      SELECT ARRAY(
        SELECT j.key
        FROM report,
          LATERAL jsonb_each(data) AS j (key, _)
        WHERE j.key LIKE 'number%'
      ) INTO _keys_to_update;
       
      FOREACH _key IN ARRAY _keys_to_update 
        LOOP
         UPDATE report
       SET data = jsonb_set(data, ARRAY[_key], to_jsonb(123));   
      END LOOP;
END $$;


When and why should I use Json type for my columns in PostgresSQL?. When you have the need of updating values in a JSONis also one of the reasons NOT to store the stuff in a JSON....

Also do not that {"number_01":14322,number_98:629578} is not valid JSON, it should read: {"number_01":14322,"number_98":629578}.

You can use sql code instead of plpgsql, it will run faster. Try this :
CREATE FUNCTION jsonb_update (input jsonb) RETURNS jsonb LANGUAGE sql AS
$$
  SELECT json_objectagg
            ( j.key :: text : 
              CASE 
                WHEN jsonb_typeof(j.value) = 'object' THEN jsonb_update(j.value)
                WHEN j.key :: text ~ '^number' THEN to_jsonb(123)
                WHEN j.value :: text ~ '^"http:// 139.168.6.44' THEN to_jsonb(replace (j.value :: text, 'http:// 139.168.6.44', 'http:// 139.168.6.55'))
                ELSE j.value
              END
            )
    FROM jsonb_each(input) AS j(key,value) ;
$$ ;

Then run the query :
SELECT jsonb_update('{"number_01":14322,"number_98":629578,"file":"http:// 139.168.6.44/upload", "nested_object":{"number_01":14322,"number_98":629578,"file":"http:// 139.168.6.44/upload"}}' :: jsonb)

you get the result :
{"file": ""http:// 139.168.6.55/upload"", "number_01": 123, "number_98": 123, "nested_object": {"file": ""http:// 139.168.6.55/upload"", "number_01": 123, "number_98": 123}}

see dbfiddle
